# Linux OpenGL programming, should I use GLX or any other?

Tags: c, linux, opengl

I'm new to OpenGL and found that there are a lot of libraries to do that in C,
and I also found that glx is most friendly with Linux X Server, I just want to do basic stuff, and I cannot find any tutorials for GLX.

Is GLX a bad thing? I just want to do some small graphical things without installing many libraries and getting confused. Can anyone suggest me something which has tutorials and simple to compile?

I found a link with an example with GLX and it worked perfect with no errors: anyone please suggest where I can find nice documentation or any better libraries.

Comment: It's unclear what problem you want solved: GLX does what you want, so what's missing?

Comment: I want to draw spheres, I found cold which draws a square in 2d

Comment: You should really edit your question to be more specific about what you want then. I don't think OpenGL has any way to draw spheres though (you'd generally "build" your own sphere out of triangles). There's bound to be libraries that abstract that away for you though..

Comment: @BrendanLong: As I recall, the GLUT libraries have some functionality for drawing primitives such as spheres. But I haven't worked with OpenGL/GLU/GLUT in many many years. Not sure if they're still that commonly used.

Comment: I can build my own sphere my question is choice for library friendly with linux

Comment: I think best way is to link with libGL and libGLU. Is is best to not make any assumption about wich opengl implementation is used as they may vary from box to box.

Comment: probably this would be a better place to ask this kind of questions http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

GLX library is written to communicate OpenGL application with the X server. It probably doesn't do anything more than that, but it's enough for you. When you create and set up your window and GL context with GLX, you start using OpenGL like everywhere else. In other hand do you really want to set up everything yourself using so low-level libraries only to draw a 3D sphere? IMO it overkill. Won't it be better for you to use a wrapper framework, like i.e. GLFW? It'll do for you everything you'll want to without need of writing a lot of redundant C-code.

And if you are using Linux, installing additional libraries (or any other package) sure won't be a problem. Every distro is using package manager, which makes installing almost anything very easy.

Comment: GLFW? It only manages windows and input + basic image loading.No geometry creation (like in GLUT) . Also drawing a sphere with "pure" OpenGL is simple.

Answer (score 1):

GLX is necessary in Linux, since it is the glue between OpenGL and the running X server.

Certainly, GLX is fairly complex for beginners, especially when the goal is learning OpenGL, and nothing more.

All libraries out there that allow OpenGL rendering uses GLX, but they wraps GLX calls in a way to simplify OpenGL-enabled window creation.

I suggest to setup your application with GLUT, since you can create a window and manage system events (i.e. Key inpus). Additionally, GLUT is available for other systems also, allowing you to port you application somewhere else.